# Not able to generate a line in graph with mysql database connected with chartist.js library?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the chartist.js library for making graphs. I didn't found a single example of it with MYSQL example. So, taking help different libraries codes available online  I am trying to insert numerical values as array as in labels(which is static though). But not able to generate graph. 
Hoew to solve this problem.
The page is filled with values of X and Y axis but no line is getting drawn when entered in browser.

The debugger says
TypeError: this.data.series[i][m] is undefined chartist.min.js:7:17185
Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.

code:

```
<head>
<script src="../_js/chartist.min.js"></script>
<link href="../_css/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Daily performance-- Aspect ratio containers</title>

 <?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("// due connectn attributes"); 
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) 
{ 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *  from Score_result");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
$player1 = array_column($row,"Player1");
$player2 = array_column($row,"Player2");
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="ct-chart ct-golden-section"></div>
 <script>
new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
 labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
 series: [
 [<?php echo implode(',',$player1); ?>],
 [<?php echo implode(',',$player2); ?>]
 ]
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In series in script:
replacing statically as 
series: [   [23,45,5,56], [3,55,5,55]  ]  works 

how pass values in series array inn this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used ChartJS before, however, i did not use json so i'm unsure what might be wrong with your code.

I pulled this out of the script i wrote where I implemented a bar chart. In this code the variable video_statistics is a multidimensional array contains data in the following form:

```
Month | Premium Users | Total Users
___________________________________
March |      8        |      12
April |      15       |      32
May   |      13       |      27
```

Code:

```
<?php   
    $months = array_column($video_statistics,"month");
    $premium_users = array_column($video_statistics,"premium_users");
    $total_users = array_column($video_statistics,"total_users");


?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var data = {
            labels: [<?php echo implode(',',$months);?>],
            datasets: [
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',',$total_users); ?>],
                    title : 'Total Users'
                },
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [<?php echo implode(',',$premium_users); ?>],
                    title : 'Premium Users'
                }  
            ]  
        }
        var cht = document.getElementById('videoChart');
        var ctx = cht.getContext('2d');
        var barChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data);
    });
</script>


<canvas id="videoChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

The code was working in the script but i haven't tested it in this form. I hope it helps.

Comment: does it 

      [<?php echo implode(',',$premium_users); ?>]

pass data to series as : [2, 5, 34 , 4 ,34 4, 43]